# Delegated Permissions to Change AD Attributes - Now which Tool do I give the Users?

Tags: active-directory

I have delegated permissions to our Executive Assistant to change Users Titles, Departments, Cell Number, and such. But I would like for her to use Outlook to change these attributes but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a tool she can use to change these attributes that does not include having to install the Admin PAK nor having to create a custom MMC Taskpad? That method seems so 1990-ish.

Comment: It would also help if you mention what version of Windows she's using, as newer versions have added functionality to do this in a more user-friendly manner, for this very reason.

Comment: While a custom MMC taskpad may seem archaic, the fact is it works. Almost every (but really probably every) Microsoft GUI tool is built on the MMC framework. In addition to that, many third party tools are built on the MMC framework as well... because it works.

Comment: We are in a Windows Server 2008R2 environment with Windows 7 Enterprise on the desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of packages out there that you can use to provide web interfaces and other methods to provide non-administrators access to the directory.  You can find some decent payware as well as a few free/OSS packages as well.

To be fair I am the project coordinator for [uManage](http://umanage.codeplex.com), an open source ASP.NET based project.